# How to gray a seekbar when disabled?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I want to make grey my seekbar when I disable it.
I know I can programmatically make this changes by changing color but I'd like to know if it is possible to do this directly in my xml activity layout.

In fact in my code I'd like to just write this:

> mySeekBarNuance.setEnabled(true);

And automatically my seekbar becomes grey.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

In your styles.xml

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"> // or the themw you are using
        ...
        ...
         <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/MySeekBarStyle</item>
   </style>
```

Add also a new style

```
<style name="MySeekBarStyle"  parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/gray</item> // put here the color for disable state
</style>
```

`controlColorNormal` is used for disabled state and `colorAccent` for enabled state

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector as background for the Seekbar

A selector set what you want if condition are met (here : `android:state_enabled="true"`)

In your activity/fragment layout you put the seekbar with a background that is a selector :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_seekbar"/>
```

You make the selector in your drawable folder :
*selector_seekbar.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <item  android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
</selector>
```

If enabled, the seekbar will be holo green, otherwise it will be gray

You can do the same thing if the seekbar is focused, pressed etc thaht way.

And you can not only set the color but an entire drawable instead